# Using Regex at the end of multiple lines

Tags: regex

Using a text cleaning app on a block of text about 50 lines long and want to get rid of the last 4 characters of each line so I'm using this:

```
.{4}$
```

However out of the 50 lines of text it only matches the final line, how can I get it to work on every line? (Obviously ^ for start of line doesn't work either)

Thanks

Comment: What "text cleaning app" are you using?

Comment: Maybe `.{4}(?=$|\n)`?

Comment: what flavor of regex? there are different ones. Fror python f.e. you would need to add the `re.M` flag für multiline

Comment: Will `(?m).{4}$` work for you?

Comment: BTW, what if a line contains fewer than four characters?

Comment: @Sweeper I'm using the app Clean Text

Comment: HaoWu and Jullio thanks to both of you that did the trick. Alexander, I can visually see 50 lines and I'm pasting it in so not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you should use the regular expression with an `m` option, which will make `^` and `$` match not only the beginning and end of the whole text, but of each line in it.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, how would I do that?

Comment: Depends on the environment in which you work. As is written in one of the comments above, you can set the `m` option within the regular expression itself by prepending it with `(?m)`.